# What would be the best way to have multiple variations of the same repo?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-fork

I'm working on an application that needs to run on 4 different computers and be the HMI for 4 different but very similar projects. I was looking at Forks and Branches on GitHub, what's different between them, pros and cons, explanations, etc. but still not finding quite the answer I need.

I was looking at having a Main/Origin repo that contains all of the shared features between the 4 applications. From there, I'm trying to think of the best way to fork/branch/copy that multiple times so that I can make changes specific to one specific variation of the app on that "branch".

I've tried with a test repo that I created, but when I try to fork it myself, it says "repository already exists". I've made a branch and tried that way, but it seems like every shared file between the Main branch and the new branch run into merge issues every time I try to merge changes from the shared Main.

I'm trying my hardest to not have 4 completely separate applications in case something needs updated on all of the versions, but right now I just have all of the versions compiled together into one big mess of an application with several variables and functions that don't get used depending on which project the application is working with at the time. Is there a good way to do this, and what would that be?

Comment: A fork is entirely separate repository (mostly a description of *how* you use Git, rather than a feature of Git). A branch is a Git feature for diverging file states in the same repository.

Comment: If it's one application, you might consider making the per-computer difference configuration options, so you have *one* version of the application and 4 different configuration files.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle

Comment: I might approach in a different way altogether: it sounds like the apps are different, but have a fair amount of shared code. Why not put the common code in a library they can all access, but each app in its own separate repo that links with that shared library?